# Нужна ли запятая в сочетании "точно как"?

Tags: пунктуация

Точно как когда-то при первой встрече.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**точно**](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/ushakov/1056354/%D0%A2%D0%9E%D0%A7%D0%9D%D0%9E)

**3. *Частица утвердительная.*** В начале ответа употребляется в значении **да, так, совершенно верно** (устар.).
*Точно, я хорошо обставлен, и дела мои недурны* (Гончаров).

**5. *Союз сравнительный.* Как, словно, будто.**
*Кричит, точно помешанный. Точно с цепи сорвался.*

Для Вашего предложения, как мне кажется, возможны два варианта.

1. "Точно" — в значении утвердительной частицы — отделяется запятой:

**— А он точно выглядит по-прежнему?

— Точно** [да, совершенно верно]**, как когда-то при первой встрече.**

2. Если "точно" выступает в роли "словно", то союз [**словно как**](https://punktuaciya.academic.ru/654/%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%BE_%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA), имеющий такой же смысл, не расчленяется (запятой нет).

**— Как он выглядит?

— Точно как** [словно как] **когда-то при первой встрече.**

Answer (score 1):

Лучше сказать: **совсем как когда-то при первой встрече.**

Дело в том, что существует сравнительный союз ТОЧНО, например: "Откуда-то тянуло затхлой сыростью, точно из погреба". И тогда в предложении будут как бы два союза подряд.

Запятая перед союзом КАК не ставится.

Розенталь:http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=147#pp147

Запятая не ставится:
если сравнительному обороту предшествует отрицание не или слова **совсем, совершенно, почти, вроде, точь-в-точь, именно, просто, прямо** и т. п.: Я воспитал в себе это чувство праздника не как отдыха и просто средства для дальнейшей борьбы, а как желанной цели (Пришв.); Дети иногда рассуждают совсем как взрослые; Было светло почти как днём; Волосы у девочки вьются точь-в-точь как у матери; Андрей Белый отдавался языку именно как шаман, отдающийся самовозбуждению (Фед.);